# Windows 8.1 Ent Hyper-V - can I enable remote audio recording in Windows 10 Pro TP (for Cortana)?

Tags: windows-8.1, remote-desktop, hyper-v, windows-10-preview, cortana

- Windows 8.1 Enterprise running Hyper-V
- Windows 10 Pro Technical Preview (build 9926) in a virtual machine

I'd like to test Cortana in Windows 10, but the microphone isn't showing up in my virtual machine. Audio does redirect through the host - sound is working - but the ability to record is not being automatically redirected.

I found that in Remote Desktop Connection, one can enable "remote audio recording" to enable microphones on the host to work with the remote client. There's also a "Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration" tool as part of a Windows Server's "Remote Desktop Services" found under "Administrative Tools" that allows controlling the redirection of "Audio and Video playback" and "Audio recording" with virtual machines, but I'm not finding this set of tools in my Windows 8 Enterprise "Administrative Tools".

Is there a way in Hyper-V on Windows 8.1 Enterprise that allows me to configure similar options to enable redirection of the recording options in virtual machines?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. When you click "Connect" on the virtual machine from within Hyper-V manager, the "Connect to (machinename)" window pops up with the "Display Configuration". If you click "Show Options", and choose the "Local Resources" tab, you'll find the "Remote Audio" settings. Choose "Record from this Computer" before connecting.